# SQL help needed to select certain rows using a WHERE CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> My first post here, so please bear with me.
>
> My Dataset

```
 t1.c1   t1.c2   t2.c1   t2.c2   t2.c3  t3.c1   t3.c2   t1.C3
 ------------------------------------------------------------
2551770  87772   87772   82272   TEST    P       922     922
2551770  87772   87772   K0328   TEST    P       922     922
2551770  99396   99396   99396   PREV    P       922     922
2809700  93000   93000   93000   ELEC    M       310     310
2809700  99397   99397   99397   PREV    M       310     310
2809700  99397   99397   G0439   PREV    M       310     310
```

> Desired Output

```
t1.C1     t1.C2  t2.C1  t2.C2  t2.C3  t3.C1  t1.C3
---------------------------------------------------     
2551770   87772  82272  82272  TEST    P     82272 (from t1.C2)
2551770   99396  99396  99396  PREV    P     99396 (from t1.C2)
2809700   93000  93000  93000  ELEC    M     93000 (from t1.C2)
2809700   99397  99397  G0439  PREV    M     G0439 (from t2.C2)
```

> I know this must use some sort of Case in the Where clause, but I am
>   having a difficult time with the syntax. I need some help to get the
>   desired output!  I listed the logic below.
>
> The logic is as follows:

```
1. If t3.C1 != 'M'
a. If t1.C2 = t2.C2 then select t1.C2
b. If t1.C2 != t2.C2 then do not retrieve this row
2. If t3.C1 = 'M'
a. If t1.C2 = t2.C2 And t2.C3 is not like 'PREV' then select t1.C2
b. If t1.C2 = t2.C2 And t2.C3 is like 'PREV' then do not retrieve this row
c. If t1.C2 != t2.C2 And t2.C3 is like 'PREV' then select t2.C2
```

>

> And, I'm thinking of code like this, but I am getting lost with my cases:

```
Select Distinct*
From t1 Inner Join t2 On t1.C2 = t2.C1 
Inner Join t3 On t1.C3 = t3.C2
Where  
  Case When t3.C1 != 'M' Then 
         Case When t1.C2 = t2.C2 Then t1.C2
              When t1.C2 != t2.C2 then /* do not retreive this row */
  Case When t3.C1 = 'M' Then
       Case When t1.C2 = t2.C2 And t2.C3 is not like 'PREV' Then t1.C2
        When t1.C2 = t2.C2 And t2.C3 is like 'PREV' then /* do not retreive this row */
        When t1.C2 != t2.C2 And t2.C3 is like 'PREV' Then t2.C2
End
```

Comment: How is t3 joined into the query?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that join.  Let me edit the code now.

Comment: I just updated it with the inner join to table 3.

Comment: The 1st (of the 6 rows) should not be retrieved according to your requirements (1b).

Comment: ypercube, do you mean the 2nd of the dataset should not be returned?  I may not have formatted the data to what you normally see, but the 1st rows in the dataset and the desired output are the column names.

Comment: @skuldouggery It might be easier to see your rules, along with sample data from each of the tables - separated, - then the final desired result.

Comment: No, I mean the 1st row. You say in **`1b. If t1.C2 != t2.C2 then do not retrieve this row`** and `87772 <>  82272`. Why is that row in the result? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Your select clause should have the filtering using a case statement:

```
SELECT Case When t3.c1 != 'M' or t1.C2 = t2.C2 
       Then t1.C2 ELSE t2.C2 END
```

Then in your where statement you have something like this:

```
WHERE (t3.c1 != 'M' and t1.C2 = t2.C2) or 
      (t3.c1 = 'M' and 
      ((t1.C2 = t2.C2 And t2.C3 != 'PREV') or 
       (t1.C2 != t2.C2 And t2.C3 = 'PREV'))
```

If you are not using wildcards there's not much reason for the LIKEs...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct /* Not sure that you need this */
    *,
    Case /* I removed the Null cases since they aren't for output */
        When t3.C1 <> 'M' Then 
            Case
                When t1.C2  = t2.C2 Then t1.C2
            End
        When t3.C1  = 'M' Then
            Case
                When t1.C2  = t2.C2 And t2.C3 Not Like 'PREV' Then t1.C2
                When t1.C2 <> t2.C2 And t2.C3     Like 'PREV' Then t2.C2
            End
    End as LongCaseExpression
From
    t1
    Inner Join t2 On t1.C2 = t2.C1
    Inner Join t3 On t1.C3 = t3.C2
Where  
    Case
        When t3.C1 <> 'M' Then 
            Case
                When t1.C2  = t2.C2 Then t1.C2
                When t1.C2 <> t2.C2 Then Null
            End
        When t3.C1  = 'M' Then
            Case
                When t1.C2  = t2.C2 And t2.C3 Not Like 'PREV' Then t1.C2
                When t1.C2  = t2.C2 And t2.C3     Like 'PREV' Then Null
                When t1.C2 <> t2.C2 And t2.C3     Like 'PREV' Then t2.C2
                Else Null /* I presume?? Not equal and not like 'PREV' */
            End
    End Is Not Null /* I assume that the C2 is never null */
```

The where clause could also have been written though it probably makes sense to keep it in parallel with the output column in the select list:

```
Where  
         (t3.C1 <> 'M' And t1.C2  = t2.C2)
     Or  (t3.C1  = 'M' And
               (t1.C2  = t2.C2 And t2.C3 Not Like 'PREV')
           Or  (t1.C2 <> t2.C2 And t2.C3     Like 'PREV')
         )
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I started with your code.  I am getting an error that states 'an expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected'.  Do you have any thoughts?  Thanks Again.

Comment: It's all the `is`s. I hadn't noticed those before.

Comment: I took those out and it still is tossing me the error.  I figured I would start with case in the Select statement - no issue.  Then, I only added the first Case for the Where,  When t3.C1 <> 'M' .  But, still getting the error

Comment: I put the query in my SQL 2012 SSMS and hit Ctrl+F5. Is seem to parse correctly. Did you miss the `Is Not Null` at the end?

Comment: I took the null items out temporarily to get things working.  However, I was doing some reading on the web and tried this to stop the error.  So far it works, but I do not fully understand why. Where PM.Procedure_Codes.Procedure_Code= Case When PM.Carriers.Carrier_ID != '922' ....

Comment: I added the next case, When t3.C1  = 'M' Then..., but it is back to giving me an error again....ugggghhhh.....  This may sound odd, but seems like the inner 'End' is being ignored for some reason.......???????

Comment: Well null is the default when you fall through the case expression anyway. I think you're talking about the lines that end in `Then Null`?

Comment: Correct, I removed the lines for Then Null just to start off a little more simple for me.

Comment: I think you've got `Procedure_Code = CASE ... END Is Not Null`. It sounds like you don't need the `Is Not Null` at the end. But you do want the cases that evaluate to null so the equality can never match.

Comment: Those "null" expressions are not causing an error though and are really just there to be explicit about what you want. Like I said, the default result is null anyway. Any way you can post what you've got that's causing the error?

Comment: thanks, sure.  but, how I do not know how to post the code in this text box so it does not look like a bunch of mixed jibberish?  Sorry, I'm new at this.

Comment: If you add it as a comment I'll grab it and you can even delete it after a minute or two if you're concerned about code security. I can sort out the jibberish.

Comment: I don't have an issue but the code is too long for the commenting tool.   I tried to trim it down by shortening the table names back to t1, t2, etc but it is still too long.  Is there any way to add attachments?

Comment: I see `End Not Null` at the last part. Sorry if I was confusing but that's the one part that does need the word `Is`. But I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `And t1.c2 =` just before the case block in the where clause. I think you need to remove that too.

Comment: Hi, okay, I think it is time to go home and drink.  I put the `IS` back in and now I get no error where previously I was getting an error.  I removed the `t1.c2 =` and now everything works where previously I needed that to get the code to not error.  Why are putting the `End Is Not Null` so critical to getting this to work?

Comment: A case block ultimately spits out a value. Languages like C++ let you treat a value in a boolean context where for instance 1 becomes true and 0 becomes false. SQL doesn't do that and in the where clause you have to do something with it like make a comparison or check to see if it's a null.